# How can I trigger a workflow in Github actions after some others had succeeded?

Tags: github-actions

I have 4 workflows with 1 job each workflow:

- workflow1.yml
- workflow2.yml
- workflow3.yml
- workflow4.yml

Additionally, I have fifth workflow that has to be triggered after the previous four had succeeded.

- workflow5.yml

I have used  `needs` in workflow5. With this approach I am not able to pick the status of the jobs in a different file:

```
jobs:
 deploy-to-staging-from-main:
   runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
   needs: [workflow1job, workflow2job, workflow3job, workflow4job]
```

workflow5.yml is not waiting for workflow1job, workflow2job, workflow3job, workflow4job.

Comment: See [`workflow_run`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_run).

Comment: [`jobs.<job_id>.needs`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idneeds) is used to specify interjob dependencies. For workflows, you need `workflow_run` event.